# How to extract xyz.arc file in ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, archive, extract

How do I extract a .ARC file in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

You must install nomarch

```
sudo apt-get install nomarch
```

after installation

```
nomarch -p arhive.arc
```

Also you have man pages for additional options

```
man nomarch
```

Comment: On executing this command getting this error
" nomarch: bad first header - not a .arc file? "

Comment: Maybe is archive demaged.

Comment: Okay!!
Is there any other way to extract this file??
I need it file urgently!

Comment: Try with unar. sudo apt-get install unar.

Comment: Only FreeARC worked for me; see my answer below. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

nomarch and unar could not recognize the ARC file that my customer sent me. Probably they operate only on older versions of the archive format.

[FreeARC](https://web.archive.org/web/20151127020212/http://freearc.org/Download.aspx) could extract the file though. It is not a Ubuntu package, but just unpack the Linux archive somewhere in your home folder and run "make install". Then you can use "unarc x archive.arc" to attack and conquer the ARC file.

Comment: Yep, same for me. nomarch didn't work, but the official FreeARC binary did. Here's a link to it: http://web.archive.org/web/20140702144430if_/http://freearc.org/download/0.666/FreeArc-0.666-linux-i386.tar.bz2

Comment: Take note that in 2020 you need quite some older dependencies to get even just `unarc` to run (and I gave up for the GUI to work at all tbh). You are probably better off running FreeArc inside wine, or using [PeaZip](https://www.peazip.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look to `unar`, it says that unar is an *unarchiver for a variety of file formats*. (done a `apt-cache search unarc` and get back this entry on a Ubuntu 13.10).